# What is the ratio of the intensities of the two sounds?

Tags: calculus, physics

**1.** Suppose that a jet engine at *50 meters has a decibel level of 130*, and a normal conversation at *1 meter has a decibel level of 60*. What is the ratio of the intensities of the two sounds?

we know that the decibel scale of loudness is **$$L=10\log (\frac{I}{I_0})$$**
$$I_0=10^{−12} \frac {watt}{m^2}$$ is the softest audible sound at 1000 hertz

**2**. Suppose that the intensity of sound is proportional to the inverse square of the distance from the sound. Based on this rule, calculate the decibel level of the sound from the jet at a distance of 100 meters

**in the first question**, do I need to have both decibels at the same amount of meters?
If I take as it is (130 and 60) the difference is 70, there fore $$70=10\log (\frac{I}{I_0})$$ $$7=\log (\frac{I}{I_0})$$ $$10^7=\frac{I}{I_0}$$ hence $10000000:1$
is it correct?
**and in the second question**. $$I=\frac{1}{d^2}$$, where *d - distance* 
$$I=\frac{1}{10^4}=10^{-4}$$ $$L=10\log (\frac{10^{-4}}{10^{-12}})$$ $$L=10\log (10^{8})=10\cdot8=80$$

Comment: $-4-(-12)\neq-16$...

Comment: except this mistake, is everything correct?

Answer (score 3):

Let $I_i$ be the intensity at 50m and $I_f$ be the intensity at 100m.

The intensity is *proportional* to the inverse of the square, but not equal to it. At 50m, we have 
$L=10log(\frac{I_i}{I_0})=130$.
From that, $I_i=10$.

Because it is proportional to the inverse of the square of the distance, $\frac{I_f}{I_i} = \frac{d_i^2}{d_f^2} = \frac{1}{4}$. Then, $I_f = \frac{10}{4}=2.5$.

Now, $L=10log(\frac{I_f}{I_0})=10log(\frac{2.5}{10^{-12}})$ which is roughly $124dB$.

Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: my system marked your answer as a wrong one.

Comment: Wow I'm sorry I just realized the jet engine started out at 50m, so the initial distance is 50m, not 1m. Let me correct the mistake

@Sarah I've edited the answer and should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

By the inverse square law, if a jet engine was $130$ db at $50$ m, then at $1$ m, it would be $2500$ times as intense, so it would be $130+10\log(2500)=163.97$db.

So the difference between the sound levels is $103.97$ db, and so the difference in intensity is $10^{10.4}=2.5\times10^{10}$  times.